# hubot fails to start with flowdock adapter

Tags: node.js, npm, hubot

```
 node: 0.10.0
 npm: 1.2.14
```

I've set the environment variables `HUBOT_FLOWDOCK_LOGIN_EMAIL` and `HUBOT_FLOWDOCK_LOGIN_PASSWORD`, and then tried the following.

Pulled down the prebuilt hubot from the hubot site.
   Modified the package.json as above.
   Run npm install

Added

```
 "hubot-flowdock": ">= 0.0.1",
```

just underneath dependencies in my `package.json`

Removed redis from hubot-scripts.json

run `npm install`

then running `./bin/hubot -a flowdock -d`

With this implementation, `./bin/hubot - flowdock`

Produces the following stacktrace:

```
    TypeError: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.
    at TypeError (<anonymous>)
    at Session.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:74:15)
    at Request._callback (/Users/gb/workspace/hubot-2.2.0/node_modules/hubot-flowdock/node_modules/flowdock/lib/flowdock.js:49:17)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/gb/workspace/hubot-2.2.0/node_modules/hubot-flowdock/node_modules/flowdock/node_modules/request/main.js:122:22)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/gb/workspace/hubot-2.2.0/node_modules/hubot-flowdock/node_modules/flowdock/node_modules/request/main.js:661:16)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/gb/workspace/hubot-2.2.0/node_modules/hubot-flowdock/node_modules/flowdock/node_modules/request/main.js:623:14)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:870:14
```

Looking at /Users/gb/workspace/hubot-2.2.0/node_modules/hubot-flowdock/node_modules/flowdock/lib/flowdock.js:49:17, that is a fail on a response statusCode > 300.

So far so good. Adding a console.log to the line above produces "401" unauthorized.

How? The credentials are correct (I log in with that email/password routinely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who cares, eventually I realized that my password was incorrect. I was attempting to use my email password, while the correct answer is to use the password you set up when you first connect to flowdock